# What command can I add to a .reg file to skip the 'asking' dialog box?

Tags: windows

Whenever I open a reg. file, a dialog box will pop up, asking whether to continue. I want to skip this step. What command can I add into a .reg file so as to skip it?

Comment: there is no way to suppress the confirmation message before a registry file is applied.  Open .reg files using a text editor, it will avoid the message, unless you use the "merge" option but the message shouldn't be displayed if your using the "edit" method tough.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've been able to find, it is not possible to suppress the confirmation message when running from a *.reg file. You can, however, use "reg add" to create the keys from command line and avoid a confirmation dialog.

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\foo" /v "bar" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
```

- /v is the value name
- /t is the data type
- /d is the data itself
- /f forces overwriting without a prompt